# combine text and files in a script

Tags: file, text, sh

I have the following problem:
I'm trying to write a script where two files (file1.txt and file2.txt) should be combined into 1 file with a text passage in between. The output should be written in another file (e.g. output.txt).

The output.txt file should be:

```
[content of file1.txt]  
text passage  
[content of file2.txt]
```

After some research on the internet I found the following and it works fine in the terminal:

```
cat file1.txt <(echo "text passage") file2.txt > output.txt
```

However, it does not work in my script:

```
 #!/bin/sh  
cat file1.txt <(echo "text passage") file2.txt > output.txt
```

If I execute the script nothing happens (the output.txt isn't written).

Why doesn't this line work in a script and what can I do to make it work?
Thank you for your help!

Stephan

Comment: does your file1.txt and file2.txt exists in your directory form where you are running the script?

Comment: yes, file1.txt and file2.txt already exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
cat file1.txt > output.txt
echo "Text message" >> output.txt
cat file2.txt >> output.txt
```

the `>>` operator means add it to the end of the file, rather than overwriting the contents.

You can also group the commands using brackets:

```
(cat file1.txt
echo "Text message"
cat file2.txt) > output.txt
```

Comment: When I try this I only get
cat: Text message: Date oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden (in german, cat can't find the file "Text message")

Comment: `echo "Text message"` instead of `cat "Text message"`. `cat` will look for the file `Text message`.

Comment: i will, but i have to wait 3 minutes until i can accept the answer ;-)